# Trouble with type inference in writing generic extension method

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I really hate sometimes how `IDictionary<TKey, TValue> [key]` will throw an exception if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Of course there is `TryGetValue()`, but that seems to have been optimized for performance and not usability.

So I thought, oh I'll just make an extension method for it - which I did :

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static TType GetValueOrDefault<TKeyType, TValue, TType>(this IDictionary<TKeyType, TType> dictionary, TKeyType key)
    {
        TType value = default(TType);

        // attempt to get the value of the key from the dictionary
        // if the key doesn't exist just return null
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            return default(TType);
        }
    }    
}
```

This works fine EXCEPT I cannot seem to get type inference working.

Obviously I want to be able to do the following :

```
var extraDataLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
extraDataLookup["zipcode"] = model.Zipcode;
```

and then be able to access the value :

```
var zipcode = extraDataLookup.GetValueOrDefault("zipcode");
var foo = extraDataLookup.GetValueOrDefault("foo"); // should be null
```

I've looked at a few things about type inference, inlucing [Jon Skeet's article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/06/making-the-most-of-generic-type-inference.aspx) and even sourcecode to `System.Linq.Enumerable` in [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) but seem to be missing something.

This works :

```
extraDataLookup.GetValueOrDefault<string, string,string> ("foo")
```

but this doesn't

```
extraDataLookup.GetValueOrDefault ("foo")
```

What should I be doing.

PS. I'm only looking for solutions to the generic type inference problem, not any other suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be defining your extension method with three generic types when you only need two. "TValue" and "TType" mean the same thing, don't they? Try this:

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
{
    TValue value;
    // attempt to get the value of the key from the dictionary
    dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: thx guys. nicely simplified. and duh - i knew 'value' was an 'out' param so i don't know why i initialized it. i typed 'out' but was thinking 'ref'.